# Modern CV - \cvitem second line indentation

Tags: moderncv

I have a moderncv \cvitem shown as below.

```
\cvitem{title}{item1, item2, ... , item(n)}
```

When the item list gets longer, it displays as following:

```
Title: item1, item2, ... 
item(n-1), item(n)
```

However, I would like to make it to look as following:

```
Title: item1, item2, ...
       item(n-1), item(n)
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I tried to apply some of the hanging indentation solutions, but I could not quite make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: Adding compilable code below

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75, vmargin=1.0in]{geometry}

\name{first}{last}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Title}

\cvitem{Subtitle}{item-loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please can you add an short, compilable code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll try to make and add compilable code.

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed response. I was working on something else, for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, class `moderncv` offers different commands you could use for your list.  I added them into the following MWE to show all possibilities.

If you insist in your list inside `\cvitem` there is some programming needed. Please have a look to the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \@initializelength{\mydefwidth}\settowidth{\mydefwidth}{\hintstyle{#2}: }
  \@initializelength{\myitawidth}\setlength{\myitawidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\mydefwidth}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }{\begin{minipage}[t]{\myitawidth}\raggedright #3\end{minipage}}% 
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Let's say we use `\mycvitem{definiens}{definiendum}`.

In command `\mydefwidth` (line 3 above) we calculate the length of the first word `definiens` (#2) including `:`.  In command `\myitawidth` (line 4) we calculate the remaining width for your following list, here `definiendum` (#3).  Line 5 is used to print the `definiens:` followed by a `minipage`, containing the list `definiendum`. Line 6 is used to add an space to the next paragraph. If no value is given (an optional value `#1`) the default value `.25em` is used. Commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are need to be able to use `@` in the code.

Please compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking} % head3, body3

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \@initializelength{\mydefwidth}\settowidth{\mydefwidth}{\hintstyle{#2}: }
  \@initializelength{\myitawidth}\setlength{\myitawidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\mydefwidth}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }{\begin{minipage}[t]{\myitawidth}\raggedright #3\end{minipage}}% 
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75, 
  showframe, % <========== just to show the typing area ================
%  vmargin=1.0in
]{geometry}


\name{first}{last}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Title}

\cvitem{Subtitle}{item-loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong, 
  item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7}

\mycvitem{Subtitl2}{item-loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong, 
  item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6mmmm, item7}

\mycvitem{Subtitl3}{item-loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong, 
  item1mmmmm, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6mmmm, item7llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll m m m m m m m m m m m m }

\mycvitem{Subtitle 4}{item-loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong, 
  item1mmmmmm, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll}

\cvitem{Subtitle}{%
\begin{itemize}
  \item loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong, 
  \item item2, 
  \item item3. 
\end{itemize}%
}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

and see the resulting pdf:

[image: result of new command]

You see first your `\cvitem` and afterwards some examples with the new command `\mycvitem`.  Then you can see in the complete pdf the result of provided commands of class `moderncv`.

Comment: I don't understand how the \newcommand block works exactly. However, I get a rough idea from your kind explanation. I added the newcommand to the moderncvheadiii.sty and used the new command \mycvitem to my list. Now, it works beautifully as you demonstrated! Thank you very much!!!