# Class moderncv - \cvitem indent from second line

Tags: moderncv, cv

Class `moderncv`, style `banking` has the indentation for `\cvitem` set up as:

```
Title: very long description that runs to the next line very long description 
that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line
very long description that runs to the next line
```

I would like the second line to be indented just a little bit like this:

```
Title: very long description that runs to the next line very long description 
  that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line
  very long description that runs to the next line
```

I want this to be a global modification, without having to be specific about indentation every time I add a new `\cvitem`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Publications}
\cvitem{Title}{very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you would like to be indented same as the First line is indented (because of the word "title") you could place the second argument of the command inside a `\parbox` and could also redefine `\cvitem` to behave like this by default... But this "a little bit" makes things harder. So, just confirm that you want a little bit and not so much as the "title"...

Comment: Yes, it's just a bit and not so much as the "title" (because in some cases the "title" is too long and adding _so much_ as makes it ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility you have is to indent the "very long description ..." to get

```
Title: very long description that runs to the next line very long description 
       that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next 
       line very long description that runs to the next line
```

If you want to get that follow please [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304541/16550). The advantage here is that every `\mycvitem` is indentend the length of given `Title:`.

If you -- as showed in your question -- only want to indent the complete paragraph a small skip you can use the following solution:

```
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{description}
    \item[\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }] #3
  \end{description}% 
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Then you can use command `\mycvitem` in your cv to get what you want like:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{first}{last}

\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{description}
    \item[\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }] #3
  \end{description}% 
  \par\addvspace{#1}}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Publications}
\cvitem{Title}{very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line}
\mycvitem{Title}{very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line}
\cvitem{Title}{very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line very long description that runs to the next line}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting cv]